# How to retry API once a specific field of response is ready?

Tags: javascript, promise

One of the fields of the responses of the API I try to call only be ready after a period of time.

How can I get the field once it is ready to fetch?

```js
const apiState = Date.now();
const callApi = () => Promise.resolve({
  field: "xxx",
  asyncField: Date.now() - apiState > 10000 ? "aaa" : undefined
});

async function waitForApiReady() {
  const response = await callApi();
  console.log({ response });
  //response.asyncField is undefined at this moment, but it will ready after 10secs or later.
  return response.asyncField;
}

waitForApiReady().then(console.log).catch(console.log);
```

Comment: Is `callApi` a mock for a real function that makes a http request, or is this your actual code?

Comment: @Bergi, it is a mock only.

Comment: And what about this `setTimeout`? What process does set the `asyncField` in your real code?

Comment: @Bergi, sorry, no offense, can you please read the question again? There is api when I call it in the beginning and it doesn’t have a asyncField, because the data is preparing that moment. After 10 secs, the data is ready, when I call it again, It will contains the data in the asyncField.  
The problem is the time to prepare could be different, maybe 10 secs or 20secs.

Comment: So the API returns a new object every time, and when calling the API after some unspecified amount of time, it will return an object with the field? It doesn't modify the previously returned object? "*How can I get the field once it is ready to fetch?*" sounds like you would know when exactly the field becomes ready to be fetched.

Comment: @Bergi, yes. I just use the const obj to simulate the data store in somewhere in api side.

Comment: Ok, in that case polling like in your answer is the only choice - it would be better if the API would respond only once the data is avaialble.

Comment: @Bergi, Thanks for your updates. Actually, I see a lot of people doing the wrong thing, such as use `setInterval` or `recursive call` to archive the same result as my answer. That's why I hope this Question and Answer can help people in the future. Ofc, we should be open to other answer and that's why I don't accept my own answer.

Comment: Actually there's nothing wrong with a recursive call (instead of a loop) as long as it returns a promise…

Comment: @Bergi, I am open to other answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a while loop to keep calling the API and only return when you get the reponses.

Also, a `wait` function is to delay each call not to utilize your program.

```js
const apiState = Date.now();
const callApi = () => Promise.resolve({
  field: "xxx",
  asyncField: Date.now() - apiState > 10000 ? "aaa" : undefined
});

const wait = ms => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function waitForApiReady() {
  let output;
  while (true) {
    const response = await callApi();
    console.log(response);
    if (response.asyncField) {
      output = response.asyncField;
      break;
    }

    await wait(5000);
  }

  return output;
}

waitForApiReady().then(console.log).catch(console.log);
```