# how to do ajax call recursively, to check if service is available

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-boot

I am trying to do ajax call recursively to check whether web service is available or not.
Here is my code

```js
function checkWebService() {
            console.log("function called")
            $.ajax({
                url:  "localhost:8085/login/checkWebServiceIsRunning",
                type: 'GET',
                success: (response) => {
                    console.log("success")
                },
                error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
                console.log("error")
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        checkWebService()
                    }, 1000)
                }
            })

        }
```

As my service is not running initially, the code from error block gets executed but after two or three times, the ajax call gets stuck, it neither goes in success nor in error.

Then I tried putting timeout in ajax code, so it gave timeout error, but even if the web service is available and server side code gets executed without any delay, ajax gives timeout issue.

Can someone help on what could be going wrong here.

Comment: Does this help?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68594022/how-to-keep-calling-a-api-once-a-specific-field-of-response-is-ready

Comment: Maybe this post will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350746/using-settimeout-with-ajax-calls/9351062

Answer (score 1):

You can use a while loop and async/await to get the response.

Also, you can add a variable count for the `attempt` to prevent infinite loop.

Furthermore, a `wait` function is added to delay each call to not utilize the program.

Note: `errorCode:789` is just an example to catch the max attempt error. you can define your own.

```js
const wait = ms => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function checkWebService() {
  const MAX_ATTEMPT = 20;
  let attempt = 0;
  while (true) {
    try {
      attempt++;

      if (attempt > MAX_ATTEMPT) throw { errorCode: "789" };

      const response = await $.ajax({
        url: "localhost:8085/login/checkWebServiceIsRunning",
        type: "GET",
      });

      return response;
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.errorCode === "789") {
        throw new Error("Exceed Max. attempt.");
      }

      console.log(err);

      await wait(1000);

      continue;
    }
  }
}

checkWebService().then(console.log).catch(console.log);
```

Comment: Interesting, will `throw` cleanly break the `while(true)` loop?

Comment: @JeremyThille, yes, it will. Any concerns I miss?

Comment: No, I just didn't know one could make an infinite `while(true)` loop and simply break it with `throw` :) I learned something

Comment: @JeremyThille, `throw` just break all the execution of the function if there is no catch handling for it.