# How can I do a async function over and over?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, while-loop, async-await

How can I do an async function over and over? I have tried doing it inside a while loop but it only does the very first line which is a console.log and nothing else.

```
import fs from 'fs-extra'
import fetch from 'node-fetch'

function wait(milliseconds) {
    const date = Date.now();
    let currentDate = null;
    do {
      currentDate = Date.now();
    } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
}

async function gasFee() {
    console.log("fetching ETH Price")
    var ethprice = await fetch('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=ethereum&vs_currencies=usd')
    var ethPriceJSON = await ethprice.json()
    console.log("fetching Ethermine GWEI")
    var etherminegwei = await fetch('https://api.ethermine.org/poolStats')
    var ethermineGweiJSON = await etherminegwei.json()
    var ethPrice = ethPriceJSON.ethereum.usd
    var ethermineGwei = ethermineGweiJSON.data.estimates.gasPrice
    var gweiPrice = ethPrice/1000000000
    var price = ethermineGwei * gweiPrice * 21000 .toFixed(2)
    var timeNow = new Date()
    if (price > 5) {
        console.log("Gas Price Logged")
        fs.appendFileSync('gasPrice.txt', '$' + price + ' | ' + timeNow + '\r\n')
    }
    else {return}
    if (price <= 5) {
        console.log(`Gas Price is $${price} at ${timeNow}`)
        fs.appendFileSync('lowGasPrice.txt', '$' + price + ' | ' + timeNow + '\r\n')
    }
    else {return}
}

while (true) {
    gasFee()
    wait(1500)
}
```

Comment: Your wait function is synchronous and thus blocking the process

Comment: With async functions use .then to process that which you fetch.

await fetch().then((res) => {console.log(res)}).

This will fetch, then is a form of saying, "once we get the results back". This result is then stored as res, and i use an arrow function to process it further.

Comment: Does this question answer you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68594022/how-to-keep-calling-a-api-once-a-specific-field-of-response-is-ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wait function is not a promise-based async function and you need to change it.
Also, you need to await your getFee() function to make an async execution.

```js
import fs from "fs-extra";
import fetch from "node-fetch";

const wait = ms => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function gasFee() {
  console.log("fetching ETH Price");
  var ethprice = await fetch(
    "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=ethereum&vs_currencies=usd"
  );
  var ethPriceJSON = await ethprice.json();
  console.log("fetching Ethermine GWEI");
  var etherminegwei = await fetch("https://api.ethermine.org/poolStats");
  var ethermineGweiJSON = await etherminegwei.json();
  var ethPrice = ethPriceJSON.ethereum.usd;
  var ethermineGwei = ethermineGweiJSON.data.estimates.gasPrice;
  var gweiPrice = ethPrice / 1000000000;
  var price = ethermineGwei * gweiPrice * (21000).toFixed(2);
  var timeNow = new Date();
  if (price > 5) {
    console.log("Gas Price Logged");
    fs.appendFileSync("gasPrice.txt", "$" + price + " | " + timeNow + "\r\n");
  } else {
    return;
  }
  if (price <= 5) {
    console.log(`Gas Price is $${price} at ${timeNow}`);
    fs.appendFileSync(
      "lowGasPrice.txt",
      "$" + price + " | " + timeNow + "\r\n"
    );
  } else {
    return;
  }
}

(async function run() {
  while (true) {
    await gasFee();
    await wait(1500);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

To compliment the accepted answer, you might consider using the built-in javascript function [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval).

This takes a function as a callback, which is executed each x milliseconds. The function returns an ID, that can be used to cancel the interval later:

```
var gasFee = function () {
    console.log("fetching ETH Price");
    // ... Rest of function
  }

  // Call gasFee() every 1500 MS
  var gasFeeIntervalID = setInterval(gasFee, 1500);

  // Cancel execution if needed
  clearInterval(gasFeeIntervalID);
```

Comment: It may append the same line in the file. Imagine the first call to the api takes 1.5 sec and the second time to call the api only take 0.1 sec and the file will apend two records (almost the same timestamp) on the file. The better approach still use await for the whole promise chain.

Comment: I'm not trying to argue for the best approach to solve the exact issue, as this is out of scope of the question. I would most likely design it entirely differently (but I like your solution!). This was just an attempt to introduce an alternative construct, that might be useful for OP and others.

Comment: Sure, I know we are not arguing but discussing. I leave the comment just to let OP or other people understand there is a possibility of `setInterval` may cause an issue of fetching duplicate data in some cases. Usually, another approach would be recursive calling but I think while loop with await is more clear and easier to maintain in this way. In some case, you may want to add max Attempt to prevent indefinite loop and while loop is easy to do it as well.

Comment: This coukd be helpful in the future and could possibly use some sort of changing a variable to a 1 or 0 and if one gets to 1 before the other call you could cancel the other call and could add extra redundancy if a call had to be made within a certain tine frame but 404'ed