# Retry axios request when response is empty

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, response

```
  await axios
    .post(
      executeBatch,
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token"),
        },
      }
    )
    .then(
      (response) =>
        this.$store.commit(
          "insertOutputFile",
          response.data.outputFile._id
        ),
    );

  alert("You can download the result");
```

so sometimes i get empty response with status code 200,
was thinking about retrying the request if that happens,
am wondering what is the correct way to approach this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retry API once a specific field of response is ready?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68594022/how-to-retry-api-once-a-specific-field-of-response-is-ready)

Answer (score 0):

I think axios interceptors will work for you.

```js
axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    return response
  },
  async function(error) {
    const originalRequest = error.config;

    if () { // condition
      originalRequest._retry = true;
    }
  }
)
```

You can create setupAxios file in your base redux directory and export it from index.js in your base redux directory.

```
export {default as setupAxios} from "./setupAxios";
```

And define setupAxios from your root index.js file

```
import * as _redux from "./redux";

_redux.setupAxios(axios, store);
```

Btw, I am using react.js, it could be a little different in vue.js.